# Is it possible to use browser-sync with deployd?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, deployd

Is there a way to user browser-sync along with deployd?  I have a deployd app running locally and I want to be able to auto-refresh the browser when I change certain files.  I can get it working with a static site because brower-sync runs it's own server, but I don't know how to integrate it with deployd, since deployd runs its own server.